# Handling of pushing menu item. Android

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

MainActivity.java:

```
    package asus.example.com.fitnessapp;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView textView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.nav_items,menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.home:
                    textView.setText("Home");
                    return true;
                case R.id.notification:
                    textView.setText("Notification");
                    return true;
                case R.id.profile:
                    textView.setText("Profile");
                    return true;
                    default:
                        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_items"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

nav_items.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="@string/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:title="@string/notifications"
        android:icon="@drawable/notification" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/person"
        android:title="@string/profile" />
</menu>
```

When user clicks on any element of the bottom navigation bar the program should add to the textview the name of this element of menu. That's why there's the following lines in code, such as `textView.setText("Home");` and other. But when user clicks on any elements, there's nothing shows int textview. What's the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `BottomNavigationView` not a menu. You need to implement the `BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
```

and then you need to set the listener in the code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottomNav);
    bottomNav.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

For this to work you need to add `android:id="@+id/bottomNav"` to your layout file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_items"/>
```

And lastly the method to handle the `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` event:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

        switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.home:
                    textView.setText("Home");
                    return true;
                case R.id.notification:
                    textView.setText("Notification");
                    return true;
                case R.id.profile:
                    textView.setText("Profile");
                    return true;
                    default:
                        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
      }
```

You will not need `onOptionsItemSelected()` or `onCreateOptionsMenu()` if you just want to use the `BottomNavigationView`.